# Calculating variance, how to determine when to use 1/n or 1/(n-1)?

Tags: statistics

I'm learning multivariate analysis. I am asked to calculate covariance of $$X=\begin{pmatrix}
3&7 \\
2&4 \\
4&7 
\end{pmatrix}$$

According to  P8 of Applied Multivariate Statistical Analysis written by Richard A. Johnson,

> $$s_{ik}=\frac{1}{n}\sum^{n}_{j=1}(s_{ji}-\bar{x}_i)(s_{jk}-\bar{x}_k)$$
>    $i=1,2,\ldots,p$ ,  $k=1,2,\ldots,p$.

However, when I using R to compute covariance. It is following this formula
$$s_{ik}=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum^{n}_{j=1}(s_{ji}-\bar{x}_i)(s_{jk}-\bar{x}_k) $$

I do not know why they are difference? How to determine when to use $\frac{1}{n}$ or $\frac{1}{n-1}$ ?

Comment: Please use `\sum` for sums, instead of `\Sigma`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of $n-1$ rather than $n$ is [Bessel's correction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_correction).

To find the variance of a probability distribution that puts probability $1/n$ at each of $n$ points, you use $1/n$, not $1/(n-1)$.  The denominator $n-1$ is used **ONLY** when **estimating** a population variance based on a sample variance.  It makes the estimator unbiased.

Unbiasedness is slightly overrated.  You get a smaller mean squared error with the biased estimator in which the denominator is $1/n$, and smaller still (in fact smallest possible) when it's $1/(n+1)$.

Answer (score 2):

Both estimators are consistent. The estimator with $1/(n-1)$ is unbiased.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias_of_an_estimator#Sample_variance